# open viber audio(.ptt) files on pc or phone

Tags: audio, viber-messenger, media-files

my viber history got corrupted, but luckily i have backedup the important conversation i needed into text format using (backup text for viber). it might have been the reason that corrupted the history since it got corrupted right after i backedup that one conversation.

the problem is the audio files are there in the viber media, but they have no extension,and i can't open them, i tried every program possible but i couldn't find a way to do it. is there a way to be able to open them on pc or phone?

Comment: Try changing their extension?

Comment: your title says something about `.ptt`, not correct?

Comment: tried changing the extension, it doesn't work, from what i found out, it can only be opened by viber.
the title says .ptt cause the audio files are saved in a folder named .ptt in the viber media folder